# UBUNTU 17.10: Issue with kvm switch

Tags: crash, 17.10, bug-reporting, kvm-switch

I had Ubuntu 17.04 running on a spare desktop, DELL 7010 (12G RAM) x64.

Had been working fine, so when prompted to upgrade given other Ubuntu upgrades have gone fine - I OKed it.

Since the upgrade a few things are happening.  The main one is I have few machines which I'm using KVM switch.  The Ubuntu is acting like when I switch away, I've logged off.  When I come back I'm at a login screen and when I sign in I have to restart all my applications.  (Initially I thought it was maybe going a sleep).

I've check power settings - set to not go off. 
I turned off screen lock to see if that would make a difference. 
I set blank screen to NEVER.

When I look at the directory /var/crash - I see new files created.
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
_usr_lib_gnome-terminal_gnome-terminal-server.1000.crash

I looked at them, didn't mean a lot to me.

Happy to post the content but I thought I would ask if there is setting I've missed to start or it's a bigger problem.  Tried doing some googling without much luck.

Running app wise when it stop: BOINC and Firefox normally.  Maybe gimp.
On 17.04 I had been running Conky but it didn't appear to be working in 17.10 and given my other problems I've not worried about it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, would appreciate any support with this as I need to switch between different computers on a regular basis and each time I lose all my unsaved work.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one.  I'm going to reimage my machine at this point as it's a test box and I can do that.  Let you know if it works better vs the upgrade.

Comment: After the re-image: same result.  Therefore it's not the upgrade but the full 17.10 appears to "log you off" if you switch away from the comptuer using the KVM-switch.  I will continue to google to see if I can find a setting to "STOP" this.  Otherwise I will have to downgrade to 17.04.

Comment: I next installed a 2nd keyboard and mouse (which we also working) but this didn't make a difference.  I had hoped it was some sort of ground detection on them.  I will try having a 2nd monitor to see if that solves it.

Comment: 2 monitor grounded

Comment: So far having a monitor "connected" not on and not using that input (seems - only been about 15m of testing) to fix the problem.  The KVM is using the VGA port.  I hooked up a display port to DVI cable and the DVI into 2nd (Could be the first but I was testing various thing like powering it off, keeping the video feed ON, having it sent to a different input).  With that cable connected (even if the output is NOT displayed anywhere - but plugged in/grounded) The system does NOT log me off.

Comment: It seems that at least 2 guys have the same problem (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761352). The bug dates from 2016 but is still open, I think the best way to get it fixed is to ask for help there. It is also in the ubuntu bugs here : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761352