# Ubuntu 17.10 - stay signed on with no Monitor

Tags: login, display, 17.10, remote-desktop, kvm-virtualization

I had previously posted (see: [UBUNTU 17.10: Issue with kvm switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969190/ubuntu-17-10-issue-with-kvm-switch))  having problems using a KVM (VGA) switch.  Anytime I switched away I would be signed off and have to sign on and restart all the applications, I was running.

After playing with various power, display and tweak setting - didn't have any luck.  Google - nothing beyond my own posting and 1 other person having the same problem.

Long story short - it appears as long as I have a monitor connected (doesn't need to be on, nor using that display) I stay connected.  I assume it's some sort of grounding issue - and I cannot simply have the cable plugged in NOT attached to a monitor.

The question: Is there a way / configuration I can set to say even with no monitor attached, I stay logged on?

I'm guessing a remote desktop won't work as I would still like to KVM to the device.  I suspect if I remote in, it will see me as a user1.  Then if I KVM there and sign on it "pick up" the connection (and drop the remote) but once I switch away it will log me off? Or will the remote desktop stay active - or is there a bettering for that too?

Other crazy suggestions?  A wire from pin X to pin Y?

Comment: are you using xorg or wayland?

Comment: It seems that ubuntu 17.10 uses wayland by default. Try using `ubuntu on Xorg` on the login screen.

Comment: And about the display detection, the computer can detect the display even when it's off, because it provides the power on the DCC channel.

Comment: Yes - wayland.  I did try Xorg once (gear icon) and appeared to get the same result.    KVM away and came back to the logon screen / restart everything.

Thanks on the correction on the DCC (I'm no EE) - my "ground" reference was my "layman" attempt at understanding.  The PC and OS knew a monitor was still there vs the KVM which it seems to think I've pulled the plug to the monitor.